# Call another file in command line (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, command

How i want to call another file in command line ?

Actually i want to create button with a command that call another file .

this is my code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.configure(bg='black') #background color
root.geometry("500x300")  #size frame

label1 = Label(text = "Setting" , font = "TIMES 15",fg = "Cyan", bg = "black"   ).pack(anchor = NW)

Button1 = Button(root, text = "Done" , fg = "black", bg = "black" , ***command = OpeningPage.foo***).pack(padx = 0 , pady = 0, anchor = NE)
Button2 = Button(root, text = "Cancel" , fg = "black", bg = "black" , command =root.quit).pack(padx = 0, pady =1, anchor = NE)



root.mainloop()
```

The bold is the command, i want the command will call my other file.

Comment: It doesn't matter for the code you posted, but the variables Button1, Button2 will not be the buttons--instead their values will be whatever pack() returns, which is None.

Comment: You can't "call" files. Are you asking how to run a new python process and give it this other file? Or, are you wanting to import a class or function from another file and run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import this file and call the particular function of it.

Answer (score 0):

you should say what you want to do with the file: just get the filename, or open and read like you'd do with the open() command.

I'll assume you want to open and read the file, and the print the lines in it.
I'm using Python 2.7, so instead of importing *tkFileDialog* you will import *filedialog*, and *tkinter* instead of *Tkinter* as explained at this [Tkinter site](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog). I looked at this [Python Course](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_buttons.php) and found some sample code with buttons cause I didn't remember quite well how to do it myself :P, and then I just added some of the features you have in yours.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog   import askopenfile  

root = Tk()

root.configure(bg='black') #background color
root.geometry("500x300")  #size frame


def callback():
    name= askopenfile(mode='r')
    file = name
    count = 0
    for line in file:
        count += 1
        print count,line.rstrip()



 label1 = Label(text = "Setting" , font = "TIMES 15",fg = "Cyan", bg="black"   ).pack(anchor = NW)

errmsg = 'Error!'

Button(text='File Open', command=callback, fg = "Cyan", bg = "black" ).pack(fill=X,padx = 0 , pady = 0, anchor = NE)
Button(text='Quit', command=root.quit ,  fg = "Cyan", bg = "black" ).pack(fill=X,padx = 0 , pady = 0, anchor = NE)
mainloop()
```

Hope this will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you mean, to *run* another Python file from this one, you need to `import os` and then when you want to run it call `os.system("python yourfile.py")`. It basically calls any command between the quotes as if from the terminal/cmd.
I would also suggest creating the buttons like this instead of the way you did it.

```
button=Button(root)
Button.pack()
```

This is because creating them as you have because as [7stud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/926143/7stud) said, *"their values will be whatever pack() returns, which is None."*